# MySQL getting JSON value

Tags: mysql, json

In my MySql players table I have a column called `achievements` and it is a text field which in this particular row has this value:

```
[  
    {  
        "value":11,
        "globalID":23000000
    },
    {  
        "value":11,
        "globalID":23000001
    },
    {  
        "value":11,
        "globalID":23000002
    },
    ...
    {  
        "value":6044730,
        "globalID":23000065
    }
]
```

Near the bottom of the array you can see this object:

```
{  
    "value":48,
    "globalID":23000062
},
```

I need to be able to parse the value field and show it as a `warhero` field. But how can I do this? The globalID will stay the same but the value changes. And because the globalID is after the `value` value I can't use what was used in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21596032/4942382

What SQL query would I need to run to get that value?

Thanks!

Comment: You need just one value from that list? Or why do you highlight a particular object? You have the `globalID` up-fromt, and want to extract the corresponding `value`?

Comment: @trincot yes I wanna be able to extract the value for the corresponding globalID but without having to fetch the entire field value

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: MySQL has no idea what JSON is, to the database it's just a text column, and by necessity the entire column must be fetched to be parsed. If you're doing heavy JSON data manipulation like this, keep in mind that [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) supports native JSON data types and has operators to extract elements like this.

Comment: It is one of the basics to normalise a database, and the very first step is to eliminate non-atomic values, as is the case here. If the design is wrong everything else becomes difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design of a table does not even meet the first normalisation level if it stores a non-atomic value in a single column, which is the case with this type of `JSON` encoded values.

Now if you have no access to the `JSON` functions [available to MySql version 5.7+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), and your **globalID** has a fixed number of digits, then you could do some string matching as follows.

For example, if you need the value that goes with **globalID** 23000062, then you could do this:

```
SELECT  players.*,
        CAST(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(achievements, '"globalID":23000062', 1),
                '"value":',
                -1
            )
        AS UNSIGNED) AS json_extracted_value
FROM    players
WHERE   INSTR(achievements, '"globalID":23000062') > 0
```

But really, you should seriously consider redesigning your database.

Answer (score 0):

You should have never saved the `JSON` in your table, you already broke the rules of relational database design.

`mysql` cannot make sense of the data, so no SQL query will help you, you have 2 options:

- Fix your database design, create tables to hold that data instead of JSON
- Fetch the data, decode the JSON, and do all type of manipulations and hacks to get your desired value.

Comment: MySql 5.7 supprorts JSON.

Comment: my point was it is not use JSON as the native way of storing data, Interesting though as I was not aware of that but still not a good idea. anyway I just looked it up and found this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search